# Search route in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

please help me build the cypher:

I have a NODES label :Station and they are connected using a directional relation :Line, where the Line property is e.g. the line number. NODES are multiple connected by different lines (with Line_ID property). I need a query about the route from Station A (e.g. id=1) to Station B (id=25), via the :Line session, but in such a way that multiple variants are offered, but each variant must have the same Line_ID in the session.
My query loops or "skips" during the search to a session with a different LINE_ID than the previous one. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

To return paths from station A with `id = 1` to station B with `id = 25` via `Line` relationships with equal `Line_ID` properties:

```sql
MATCH (:Station {id: 1})-[r:Line]->+(:Station {id: 25})
WHERE all(i IN range(0, size(r)-2) WHERE r[i].Line_ID = r[i+1].Line_ID)
```

Comment: this solution don't work, if i try explain function, small db got in last operation 413 405 924 401 rows :(

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are actually errors in the results?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an efficient query, since the variable-length relationship pattern `[rs:Line *0..9 {id: r1.id}]` specifies a static `id`:

```
MATCH path = (start:Station {id: 1})-[r1:Line]->(:Station)
    -[:Line *0..9 {id: r1.id}]->(:Station {id: 25})
RETURN path
```

I imposed an arbitrary upper bound of 9 (for a total path length of up to 10) to avoid taking too long or running out of memory. Adjust the bound as appropriate for your data.

It is important to recognize that variable-length relationship queries have exponential complexity. If each node has `R` relevant relationships, then a path length upper bound of `N` can result in `R**N` database lookups. This is why it is important to set a reasonable upper bound (`N`).

###### Specific `Line` `id`

If you want to specify the `Line` `id` to use, then the query can be simpler and much quicker (but you should still impose an upper bound on the path length). This query assumes you pass the following [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/):

- `$line_id`: the desired `id` value
- `$station_id_first` and `$station_id_last`

  ```
  MATCH path = (:Station {id: $station_id_first})-[:Line *..9 {id: $line_id}]->(:Station {id: $station_id_last})
  RETURN path
  ```

Comment: chatgpt correct me query (s1:Station), second row: MATCH (s1)- ... etc, but this query running about 5min, then fail to memory allocation error - see: https://pasteboard.co/ISeiwR6UJYSt.jpg

Comment: I modified my answer to impose an upper bound, which is always best practice.

Comment: I have change relation name from Line to "Section" and property id set_id but same result, .. long executing and fail..  if I specify set_id in WHERE clausule like `MATCH path = (start:Station {id: 61})-[r1:Section]->(:Station)
    -[:Section *0..9 {set_id: r1.set_id}]->(:Station {id: 64})
    WHERE r1.set_id = 2
RETURN path` it works perfect and quickly, but i dont know excatly set_id in future, i need got x variants and then customer choose best transportation route.

Comment: Yes, if you limit the query to a specific `set_id`, it will be much faster. But my query is for finding ALL "consistent-Section-id" paths, not just ones for `set_id = 2`. You can try setting changing the upper bound from `9` to something lower, say `5` to see how fast the query is. I have added a new paragraph to my answer to discuss the exponential complexity of variable-length relationship queries.